# How to scrape this database site?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrape

I wanted to scape this site, but it seems like the information is not in html code. How to scrape this site/information?

https://golden.com/query/list-of-incubator-companies-NMB3

I have tried to use normal html scraping, but I am currently not that much familiar with scraping at all.

Answer (score 2):

This site uses javascript to render it's content, however you can use it's api to scrape all of the data in json format.

The api endpoint is:

```py
url = f"https://golden.com/api/v1/queries/list-of-incubators-and-accelerators-NMB3/results/?page={page_number}&per_page=25&order=&search="
```

And a simple scrapy example could look something like this.

```py
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'golden'

    def start_requests(self):
        for page_num in range(1,4):
            url = f"https://golden.com/api/v1/queries/list-of-incubators-and-accelerators-NMB3/results/?page={page_num}&per_page=25&order=&search="
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.json()
        yield {"data": data["results"]}
```